# Add total-count in meta data using JSON API .Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, json-api

I'm using the [JSON API .Net Core](https://json-api-dotnet.github.io/#/) to create .Net API. How to add **total-count** in meta-data?
[image]

```
public class BaseEntity : Identifiable, IHasMeta
    {

        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, object> GetMeta(IJsonApiContext context)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, object> {
            { "copyright", "Copyright Croos" },
            { "authors", new string[] { "Croos" } }
        };
        }
    }
```

There is nothing about it in the document.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, enable the `IncludeTotalRecordCount` options:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ... other services

    services.AddJsonApi<AppDbContext>(o =>{
        o.IncludeTotalRecordCount = true;
    });
}
```

And now we can retrieve the total records by `context.PageManager.TotalRecords` :

```
public class Person : Identifiable, IHasMeta
{
    [Attr("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> GetMeta(IJsonApiContext context)
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object> {
            { "total-records", context.PageManager.TotalRecords },
        };
    }
}
```

**A working demo :**

[image]